# Run command on all files within a directory

Tags: xml, shell, unix, sed, information-retrieval

I'm trying to remove multiple XML tags from many files in a folder. I tried sed, but it only works on one file at a time.

This is the sed code I used for removal from individual files. The folder that contains multiple files is called `rcv1`.

```
sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' sk.xml

a.xml  
b.xml  
c.xml   
d.xml
```

The code I'm trying to use is:

```
for file in *.xml do sed -e 's/v[^]*>//g' "$file"
```

Edit: Prepending `find ./ -type f -exec` worked in combination with fedorqui's answer:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/<[^>]*>//g' {} \;
```

Comment: Mate im tryna remove multiple xml files, not one, ive got a lot in the folder. I just know to do it in linux

Comment: Is your goal to just remove the *file*, or are you trying to do some kind of processing *in* the file?

Comment: Note to future readers: The reason for the odd voting pattern was due to a meta-discussion on this question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309896/they-ask-i-answer-they-delete-what-can-i-do-and-what-should-i-have-done?cb=1

Comment: @Mrnerd Please don't vandalize the question.

Answer (score 21):

If your `sed` command is working for a given file and you want to do the same for all the files indicated in your file `rcv1`, just loop through the content of the file as indicated in [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001):

```
while IFS= read -r file
do
    sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' "$file"
done < "rcv1"
```

It may be that you want to do this to all the files in a given directory, instead of reading them from a file. In this case, loop through the files in the current directory using a `for` loop:

```
for file in *
do
    sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' "$file"
done
```

Also, if you want these files to change, you may want to use `-i` so that the changes occur in-place. That is, the file itself gets modified with the new version. For safety, say `sed -i.bak` so that a backup file is created.

All together:

```
sed -i.bak -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' "$file"
```

Comment: Great one @fedorqui

Comment: @ThomasAyoub thanks : ) It seems like it was only yesterday that I got my first +1!

Comment: @fedorqui certainly, *somewhere*, yesterday means 3 years and a half ago :p